# Spring configuration for using 2 hibernate sessionFactories

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to use 2 hibernate db connections. I am facing this error, i tries to solved if but could not find a way. I have made two different configuration files and annotated @bean and @qualifires but it still dosent work.

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [com/project/configuration/RepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: sessionFactory2,sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: sessionFactory2,sessionFactory
```

My configurations :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class RepositoryConfig2 {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean(name="sessionFactory2")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory2() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory2 = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory2.setDataSource(dataSource2());
    sessionFactory2.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    sessionFactory2.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.project" });
    return sessionFactory2;
}

@Bean
public Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect2"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql2"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");// environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")
    return properties;
}

@Bean(name = "datasource2")
public DataSource dataSource2() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource2 = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource2.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName2"));
    dataSource2.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url2"));
    dataSource2.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username2"));
    dataSource2.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password2"));
    return dataSource2;
}


@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory2")
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager2 = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager2.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager2;
}
```

}

Second Configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean(name="sessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.project" });
    return sessionFactory;
}

 @Bean
 public Properties hibernateProperties() {
 Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
 properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
 properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");// environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")
 return properties;
 }

@Bean(name = "datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

 @Bean
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory")
 public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
 HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
 txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
 return txManager;
 }
```

}

Comment: why `@Bean` and `@Autowired` on same method ?

Comment: yes, realized that earlier. thanks by the way problem is solved(lots of r&d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I did more R&D and with luck i solved the problem..

So here's what i did

1. Merged my RepositoryConfiguration into one class.
2. Removed Autowired from HibernateTransactionManager and manually wired sessionFactories.
3. Also cjanged packages to scan for hibernate(realized it will create same tables in both databases)
4. Add qualifier in  @Transactional(import from spring.)

   ```
   @Transactional("sessionFactoryTransactionManager")
   ```

   in my repositories.

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   @PropertySource({ "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
   public class RepositoryConfiguration {

   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

   @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
       LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
       sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
       sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
       sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.project" });
       return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public Properties hibernateProperties() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.put("hibernate.dialect",    environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
       properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
       properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");// environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")
   return properties;
   }

   @Bean(name = "sessionFactory2")
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory2() {
       LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory2 = new  LocalSessionFactoryBean();
       sessionFactory2.setDataSource(dataSource());
       sessionFactory2.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties2());
       sessionFactory2.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.server" });
       return sessionFactory2;
   }

   @Bean
   public Properties hibernateProperties2() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect2"));
       properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql2"));
       properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update2");// environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")
       return properties;
   }

   @Bean(name = "datasource2")
   public DataSource dataSource2() {
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName2"));
          dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url2"));
      dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username2"));
      dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password2"));
       return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean(name = "datasource")
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
       dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
   dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
   dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
   return dataSource;
       }

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("sessionFactory2")
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory2;

   @Bean(name = "sessionFactoryTransactionManager")
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(this.sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
   }

   @Bean(name = "sessionFactory2TransactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager2() {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager2 = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager2.setSessionFactory(this.sessionFactory2);
       return txManager2;
   }

   }
   ```